# execute a method in case clicking a button

Tags: javascript

i'm having lot of troubles with JS, please help me a lit

i have a button at HTML

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-dark" onclick="">View/button>
```

at another JS file i have a method

```
updateBot = async (bot) => {
    const response = await ownFetch.put('/rest/api/bot/update', {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(bot)
    });
    return await response.json()
        .catch(err => console.log(err.status));
};
```

how to execute a method in case clicking a button??

maybe it's simple question, but my mind is blow

thank you for your answers!

Comment: This is how you do `onclick="updateBot()"`, When button is clicked the `updateBot()` function invokes.

Comment: but i got error is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Comment: Wrap your code in `DOMContentLoaded` function. [Read this Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)

Answer (score 0):

You need to select that button and add an event listener.

HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-dark" id="btn">View/button>
```

JavaScript:

```
const btn = document.getElementById("btn")
btn.addEventListener("click", updateBot)

updateBot = async (e) => {
        // what is bot???
        const response = await ownFetch.put('/rest/api/bot/update', {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(bot??)
        });
        return await response.json()
            .catch(err => console.log(err.status));
    };
```

Comment: bot - is a object